# How to use setStroke in android GradientDrawable?

Tags: android, border, drawable

I came across a strange problem when trying to use Android's `GradientDrawable`.
This is my current code:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
int _1dp = (int) getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
drawable.setStroke(_1dp, borderColor);
setBackground(drawable);
```

But it doesn't work unless I add this at the end of the above:

```
setPadding(_1dp, _1dp, _1dp, _1dp);
```

I don't understand why I would need to add `_1dp` of padding to each side in order to make a gradient display properly.

Is there something I've missed?

Thanks